# How to group sub strings in Teradata?

Tags: teradata

I have the following table in Teradata 14 , however I am not allowed to write procedures and functions myself

```
id  property
1   1234X (Yel), 2345Y (Red), 1234X (Gre),
2   2222Y (Pin), 2222Y (Red), 2222Y (Gre),
3   3454E (Yel), 4565Y (Whi), 3454E (Red),
```

All rows are in the same fashion. E.g. row 1 : `1234X` is an object that has attributes `(Yel)` and `(Gre)` . Whereas `2345Y` has `Red`

---

How can I group the above table so that each object would have all attributes listed in one brackets

```
id  property
1   1234X (Yel Gre), 2345Y (Red), 
2   2222Y (Pin Red Gre ),
3   3454E (Yel Red), 4565Y (Whi),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
WITH chunk(id,property,a,b,c,combined) AS
(SEL id,
 property,
 STRTOK(property, ',', 1) AS a,
 STRTOK(property, ',', 2) AS b,
 STRTOK(property, ',', 3) AS c,
CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(TRIM(a),1,5)=SUBSTRING(TRIM(b),1,5) AND SUBSTRING(TRIM(a),1,5) <>SUBSTRING(TRIM(c),1,5)
            THEN SUBSTRING(TRIM(a),1,10) || ' ' || SUBSTRING(TRIM(b),8,3)||')'||','||c||','
      WHEN  SUBSTRING(TRIM(a),1,5)=SUBSTRING(TRIM(c),1,5) AND SUBSTRING(TRIM(a),1,5)<>SUBSTRING(TRIM(b),1,5)
            THEN SUBSTRING(TRIM(a),1,10) || ' ' || SUBSTRING(TRIM(c),8,3)||')'  ||','||TRIM(b)||','  
      WHEN  SUBSTRING(TRIM(a),1,5)=SUBSTRING(TRIM(b),1,5) AND    SUBSTRING(TRIM(a),1,5)=SUBSTRING(TRIM(c),1,5)  
        THEN    SUBSTRING(TRIM(a),1,10) || ' ' || SUBSTRING(TRIM(b),8,3)||'  '||SUBSTRING(TRIM(c),8,4)||','                               
      ELSE 'Condition failed'
 END AS combined                            
 FROM Table2)
SELECT id,combined FROM chunk 
ORDER BY id  ;
```

OUTPUT #

```
    id  combined
    1   1234X (Yel Gre),2345Y (Red),
    2   2222Y (Pin Red Gre),
    3   3454E (Yel Red),4565Y (Whi),
```

Dynamic way :
[Is it possible to group string within a string in Teradata?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20155600/is-it-possible-to-group-string-within-a-string-in-teradata)

Modified#

```
SEL id
  , property
  , SUBSTRING (property FROM 1 FOR INSTR(property, ',', 1, 1)-1 ) AS a
  , SUBSTRING (property FROM INSTR(property, ',', 1, 1)+1 FOR INSTR(property, ',', 1, 2) -INSTR(property, ',', 1, 1)-1 ) AS b
  , SUBSTRING (property FROM INSTR(property, ',', 1, 2)+1 FOR INSTR(property, ',', 1, 3) -INSTR(property, ',', 1, 2)-1 ) AS c 
  ,CASE 
      WHEN SUBSTRING(TRIM(a),1,5)=SUBSTRING(TRIM(b),1,5) AND SUBSTRING(TRIM(a),1,5)<>SUBSTRING(TRIM(c),1,5) 
         THEN SUBSTRING(TRIM(a),1,10) || ' ' || SUBSTRING(TRIM(b),8,3)||')'||','||c||',' 
      WHEN SUBSTRING(TRIM(a),1,5)=SUBSTRING(TRIM(c),1,5) AND SUBSTRING(TRIM(a),1,5)<>SUBSTRING(TRIM(b),1,5) 
         THEN SUBSTRING(TRIM(a),1,10) || ' ' || SUBSTRING(TRIM(c),8,3)||')' ||','||TRIM(b)||','
      WHEN SUBSTRING(TRIM(a),1,5)=SUBSTRING(TRIM(b),1,5) AND SUBSTRING(TRIM(a),1,5)=SUBSTRING(TRIM(c),1,5)
         THEN SUBSTRING(TRIM(a),1,10) || ' ' || SUBSTRING(TRIM(b),8,3)||' '||SUBSTRING(TRIM(c),8,4)||','
      ELSE 'Condition failed' 
   END AS combined
FROM table2 ;
```

Comment: Thank you. It has a syntax err: `expecting something between ')' and   '',' `

Comment: @Buras for me it is running Well , in which line you are encountering error ? may be u need format query on your side ? or may be u need select whole query for copying and do you have STRTOK function ?

Comment: I copy pasted exactly as it is . The error is here : `CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(TRIM(a),1,5)=`

Comment: @Buras I has posted new query in modified part , Try it and let me know . mine is 14.10 version

Comment: I find out what the problem was . Apparently I had to use `substr` instead of `substring` . I do not know why but when i use `substr ` it works