# How to concatenate strings in Teradata

Tags: sql, teradata

I use `Teradata 14` with all `strtok` and other new functions , but i am not allowed to write my own functions .

In the following table each person has many skills . How can I concatenate those skills ?

```
team    person
1       Mike (swi)
1       Nick (dri)
1       Mike (coo)
2       
3       Kate (swi)
3       Kate (coo)
3       Kate (dri)
3       Wend (fly)
4       Pete (jum)
```

---

Desired table is

```
team    person
1       Mike (swi coo), Nick (dri),
2       
3       Kate (swi coo dri), Wend(fly),
4       Pete (jum),
```

How can I concatenate strings ?

Comment: is it possible to have the skills and the person name as separate columns?

Comment: sure . since all names are 4 characters and all skill are 3 characters . i can create two new columns as following `substring(person,1,4)` and `substring(person(6,8)`

Comment: This is almost the same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23021930/how-to-group-substrings-in-teradata-14 Are you guys working for the same company trying to solve the same problem with denormalized data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use recursive queries to do such thing without the use of UDFs. I have given you the query to aggregate skills use similar approach to get the end result.

```
CREATE Volatile Table TempTable1
as
(
SELECT 
team
,substr(person,0,Index(trim(person),'(')) as name
,substr(person,Index(person,'(')+1,3) as skill
,Row_Number() Over(Partition by team,name order by skill) as rnk
from
MainTable)
WITH DATA
Primary Index(team,name)
ON COMMIT Preserve Rows;



CREATE VOLATILE TABLE temp_table2 (team,name)
as
(WITH RECURSIVE temp_table3 (team,name,skill,rnk,lev)
AS
(
SELECT team,name,cast(skill as varchar(1000)),rnk,1 as lev
from TempTable1
where rnk = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT t1.team,t1.name,t1.skill||','||t2.skill,t1.rnk,t2.lev+1 
FROM
TempTable1 t1
Inner join
temp_table3 t2
on t1.team = t2.team
AND t1.name = t2.name
AND t1.rnk = t2.rnk + 1
)
SELECT team,name||'('||skill||')' as new_name
from temp_table3 
qualify rank() over (partition by team,name order by lev desc) = 1)
WITH DATA 
ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;
```